# How to get individual bytes from a SQL binary field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a binary field in SQL Server which I want to read one byte at time in a SQL function.  In code I would use a byte array. Is there an equivalent in SQL?

I couldn't find anything with google.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SUBSTRING function should be sufficient. A quick example, assuming table MyTable with column SomeData, binary(10) not null:

```
DECLARE
  @OneByte  binary(1)
 ,@Loop     int


SET @Loop = 0
WHILE @Loop < 10
 BEGIN
    SET @Loop = @Loop + 1

    SELECT @OneByte = substring(SomeData, @Loop, 1)
     from MyTable

    --  Process accordingly
 END
```

There are fancier set-based ways to do this, but for short values this should be adequate.

Comment: Will this then first convert the binary to a string before it performs substring? Is this the best way in terms of performance?

Comment: As per Books Online for SQL 2008: "Returns character data if expression is one of the supported character data types. Returns binary data if expression is one of the supported binary data types. The returned string is the same type as the specified expression with the exceptions shown in the table."

Comment: As for performance, if you have massive amounts of data to convert, or sub-second processing is required, determining an ideal process would require significant testing time and effort.

Comment: Agreed! But everywhere I search onlinesahes use substring so I don't have many options to test at this stage :) I'll keep looking

Comment: Post a question on SO with your problem. I'm thinking there's probably a better solution using tally tables and cross applys...

Answer (score 7):

You could loop through the binary field using [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

```
declare @BinaryColumn binary(5)

set @BinaryColumn = convert(binary,'abcde')

declare @Counter int, @ColumnLength int
set @Counter = 1
set @ColumnLength = LEN(@BinaryColumn)

while (@Counter <= @ColumnLength) begin
    select SUBSTRING(@BinaryColumn, @Counter, 1)
    set @Counter = @Counter + 1
end /* while */
```

Answer (score 3):

Varbinary as a type will act as a byte array, and you can read an individual byte from it using substring.