# Linq to Entities, .Take() on VARBINARY field results in ArgumentException 'DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table in my SQL Server database which stores file contents. I'm using Linq to Entities to access the data, but I don't want to grab the entire file contents, just the first 2048 bytes. (To save time, bandwidth, memory, ....)

The entity is called 'FileAccess', with the relevant fields being 'FileAccessId INT', and 'FileContent VARBINARY(MAX)'.

I've tried the following Linq:

```
IQueryable<IEnumerable<byte>> q = from fa in FileAccesses
                                  where fa.FileAccessId == 77868
                                  select fa.FileContent.Take(2048);

IEnumerable<byte> buffer = q.FirstOrDefault();

return buffer;
```

And get the ArgumentException, DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument.Parameter name: argument.

Is there a way to make this work? Or a better way to only grab a portion of a VARBINARY field?

Comment: I'm pretty sure EF doesn't support this, but I won't post as answer because I'm not certain.

Comment: I think you can use [Substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660248/how-to-get-individual-bytes-from-a-sql-binary-field) in SQL, not sure how that would be done via EF though.

Comment: @juharr I saw that as well. Unfortunately, fa.FileContent.ToString().Substring(0, 2048) gives a NotSupportedException, "Values of type 'Binary' can not be converted to string."

Comment: `Take()` is for pagination (give me the first 200 results). That is why it's usually combined with `Skip()`. It won't work when operating on a single property. The reason it appears in the suggestions is because any string is by definition an IEnumerable of characters.

Comment: @krillgar The problem isn't that `Take` is the wrong thing to do here.  It's that EF doesn't have a translation for that to SQL.  I'm guessing FileContent is mapped as a `byte[]` by EF, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: @juharr You are correct.

Comment: @Vyskol Yeah, I think the issue is that `Substring` being used on `VarBinary` just isn't mapped to by EF.  You could always do it via ADO.Net though.

Comment: You are simply using .Take in the wrong way. It's for taking a certain number of elements from a sequence, not for restricting the size of the data returned from a column.

Comment: @JohnSaunders In this context, I'm using the [Enumerable.Take<TSource> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx), as FileAccess.FileContent is mapped to a byte[] type. This works after enumeration, but I would rather not pull back the entire file contents if I don't have to and was hoping EF would translate it to the Substring sql function, or something similar.

Comment: So you wanted `q` to return `IEnumerable<byte>` with 2048 bytes in the sequence, so that `FirstOrDefault` would return the first byte?

Comment: @JohnSaunders FirstOrDefault() will return the first record that matches the criteria. The record content will be the first 2048 bytes of the FileContent field.

Comment: What is the data type of `q`? I suggest you hover over it and see.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `IQueryable<IEnumerable<byte>>`. After enumeration (`FirstOrDefault()`), `IEnumerable<byte>` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like EF supports this functionality.

I ended up creating a user defined scalar function as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SubBinary','FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.SubBinary;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION SubBinary(@contents VARBINARY(MAX), @start INT, @length INT)
RETURNS VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @length);
END
GO
```

And adding it to my Context [as described in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456847%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#feedback).

Then calling it as follows:

```
var q = from fa in FileAccesses
        where fa.FileAccessId == fileId
        select SubBinary(fa.file_content, 1, length);

return q.FirstOrDefault();
```

`fileId` and `length` are passed-in parameters.
Return type is `IEnumerable<byte>`.

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't support VARBINARY well (or anything else for that matter), but you can work-around this by creating a view.

```
CREATE VIEW FileAccessPreview AS 
SELECT FileAccessId, SubString(FileContent, 0, 2048) as FileContentPreview
FROM FileAccess
```

Comment: P.S. The answer to just about every EF question is "Create a view/table function/proc". It's ability to generate SQL queries is laughable.

Comment: I'd considered this as well. My other alternative is to write a scalar sql function and import it into my context. This would allow me to pass in the number of bytes I want returned. But I was hoping there'd be a simpler solution.

Comment: @Vyskol, you can do that? Wow, that's going to solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Sure can.
[How to: Call Custom Database Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456847%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)