# SQL Server `like` for varbinary datatype in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-like, varbinary

I have a table with a column of type `varbinary` in SQL Server

How to get records that contains an array of bytes in this table in Entity Framework?

A query like this:

```
var query = from x in context.table
            where x.varbinaryfield like (byte array)
            select x;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27365673/861716